# Define and get values from angularJS table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my angularjs code to get values in a table and save. If I put some data in  table and save, Its working fine but if I click save without entering any data in table it shows error as

TypeError: $scope.item is undefined

Here is my code and please help me. I am a newbie in angularJS

```
    <div ng-app="Myapp">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-messages.js"></script>
         <script>
            var Myapp = angular.module('Myapp', ["ngRoute"]);
        </script>

        <div ng-controller="orderFormController">
            <table  id="item_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="headings">
                        <th class="column-title">Item </th>            
                        <th class="column-title">Rate</th>                          

                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>         
                            <input type="text" name="item"  ng-model='item[0]'>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name="rate"  ng-model='rate[0]'> 
                       </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>         
                            <input type="text" name="item"  ng-model='item[1]'>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name="rate"  ng-model='rate[1]'> 
                        </td>

                    </tr>


                </tbody>

            </table>
            <button type="button"  ng-click='saveorder()' >SAVE ORDER</button>
        </div>    
        <script>
            Myapp.controller('orderFormController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
                var data = {};
                data['item'] = [];
                $scope.saveorder = function () {
                    var rowCount = 3;
                    for (i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
                        data['item'][i] = {'item': $scope.item[i], 'rate': $scope.rate[i]}

                    }
                    alert(data);
                }

            }]);
        </script>
```

Comment: Try `var rowCount = 2` or more dynamically, `var rowCount = $scope.item.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.item` is not defined anywhere except for in that for loop, if there are no values in the table, then `$scope.item` will remain undefined. You could simply declare it prior to the for loop, and set some init values, which could be done in the controller, or by using the ng-init directive.

Also, I would recommend using the ng-repeat directive for your table rows, it will create a template per item from a collection, which makes your code easier to manage. Here's the documentation: [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: Thanks @zachperkitny , Now its working fine. Here I have hard coded rows only because I couldn’t get value of dynamically created rows. I created new rows by appending it by $('#item_table tbody').append(response);

Answer (score 0):

modify your html to only include this not 2 rows of input

```
<td>         
   <input type="text" name="item"  ng-model='item'>
</td>
<td>

   <input type="text" name="rate"  ng-model='rate'> 
</td>
```

and modify your `saveOrder`

```
$scope.saveorder = function () {
       if (!($scope.item.length && $scope.rate.length)){
              alert('can\'t be empty');
              return;
       }
       data['item'].push({'item': $scope.item, 'rate': $scope.rate});
       $scope.item = "";
       $scope.rate = "";
       console.log(data['item'][data['item'].length - 1]);
       alert(data);
}
```